# Force a core to dump from an active, normally running program on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, coredump

I'm writing error handling code for a server on FreeBSD.  For extremely serious errors I want to avoid data corruption by immediately terminating.  That's easy, `exit(3)`.  Before I exit, I output my relevant variables that led me there.  However, ideally, this termination would be accompanied by a `.core` so that I could fully investigate what got me to this catastrophic (and likely hard to reproduce) state.

How can I force this to happen?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`kill -QUIT process_id` will cause a core dump from a running process (assuming that resource limits allow it).

Or see `man 3 abort` for causing a program to dump itself.

**Added**: From an interactive shell, a running program can be made to abort with the quit key, usually <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>, which sends a SIGQUIT just as the more common <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> sends a SIGINT. This is identical to the `kill -QUIT…` it's just easier to type if you are on the controlling terminal. See `man 1 stty` if your default quit key is different.

Comment: You can also use kill -3 [pid] - same deal, less typing. You can see the other kill flags on the manpage: man kill.

Comment: Well, I want to do it from the process itself; so `abort(3)` seems ok but from some testing here I don't seem to be able to access any symbols when examining the resulting `.core`.  I can get a backtrace fine, but if I try to print any of my variables they aren't found.  Is this expected with `abort(3)` or am I doing something stupid? `gcc -g -O0 test.c -o test` then `./test` then `gdb ./test test.core`

Comment: I think your problem is with using gdb: you need to pick a frame from the `where` backtrace to give scope to the variable names. See http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Selection.html#Selection

Answer (score 9):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18354686/why-coredump-files-is-not-generating-here?noredirect=1&lq=1) helped me!
`kill -11` always works for me. 11 is SIGSEGV (invalid memory reference)

Answer (score 5):

You might also want to take a look at gcore(1) (http://man.freebsd.org/gcore).

Answer (score 3):

I had no luck with `kill -QUIT` in a particular case. What worked for me is:

```
gdb --pid <process_id> -ex "set confirm off" -ex generate-core-file -ex q
```

Comment: Use `--batch` and you can skip the `-ex "set confirm off"` and `-ex q`.

Answer (score 1):

On sles12.. Below code worked for me :

```
kill -11
```

The previous suggestions did not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try `kill -BUS <pid>`
which worked for me (though on ubuntu 20.04)