# Why Coredump files is not generating here?

Tags: c, shell, linux-kernel, arm, coredump

I have a situation here, a few days back I was able to see a core- dump file on my target board, I have enabled the core-dump generation by adding "ulimit -c unlimited" to my /etc/profile.

But then someone told me, this will **only** take affect for program launched from a login shell, not for processes/services started by *systemd*, etc. and the *ulimits* are set at another location.

So I changed /etc/limits file and added `ulimit -c unlimited` line, but still I could not see core-dump file.

I am running `kill -9 $$` to generate segmentation fault and it in turn will generate core-dump file as it was doing earlier.

We tried changing "/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern" file and running `ulimit -c unlimited` explicitly but this was not enough.

Where we are going wrong?

Comment: The `-9` to the `kill` command is the `KILL` signal, and will simply terminate the process without a core-dump.

Comment: So @JoachimPileborg what you suggest ,how can I use kill command in my case??

Comment: See e.g. [this question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6561194/440558).

Comment: I tried kill -3 $$ but I am still not getting any core dump file.

Comment: Also, why use `$$`? It expands to the pid of the *shell* you're running in.

Comment: Yes @JoachimPileborg , I am expecting killing shell will give me a segmentation fault .Is it wrong or what??

Comment: If you are using bash, you should read [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Signals.html) where it says: "In all cases, Bash ignores SIGQUIT."

Comment: @JoachimPileborg core are generating now, used kill -6 $$ but problem I have to run ulimit -c unlimited manually,its not taking it from /etc/limits file ,any idea??

Comment: Because the `/etc/limits` file should not contain the *command*, it has a [different format](http://swoolley.org/man.cgi/5/limits). Besides, it's probably not used on modern Linux distros. Instead check `/etc/security/limits.conf` and its [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I don't have etc/security/limits.conf  in my filesystem ,is there any way to set it in /etc/limits like set core=-1

Comment: Linux kernels can be configured without `core` support.  See that **CONFIG_ELF_CORE** is set for your Linux kernel.  Then the standard *user space* information applies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`kill -9` will not generate a *core* file.  The command `kill -l` gives a list of supported signals.  `kill -6` or `kill -SIGABRT` should produce a core file.  As well as most other *signals* such as `kill -BUS`, `kill -SEGV`, etc.

Answer (score 6):

kill -11 always works for me. 11 is SIGSEGV (invalid memory reference)

Comment: But that is a bad idea. Some weird programs might *catch* `SIGSEGV`; `SIGABRT` is much more conventional, and the few programs catching it knows about it meaning.

Answer (score 2):

You have to first off enable user limits settings to ensure that core files can be created.

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

Application user must run as and before you start the application in the same session. This setting is inherited by the application, so what ever the ulimit is set as before starting the application is what the ulimit setting will be for the application (unless a start script changes it).

Answer (score 0):

In addition of the other answers, you might also use [gcore(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcore.1.html) to generate a *core* dump of some *running* process.

But if using [kill(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html) command (or the underlying [kill(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) syscall, e.g. from some ad-hoc program), I recommend using `SIGABRT` (the signal that [abort(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/abort.3.html) send to itself after unblocking it), as documented in the [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).

Beware, a program can usually forbid core dumping, e.g. by calling [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) with `RLIMIT_CORE` set to 0 or handling or ignoring some signals (with e.g. [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html)...).