# core file not created on a segmentation fault on ARM

Tags: linux, arm, coredump

I have an ARM executable[ (Debug build) ELF 32 bit LSB executable, ARM version (SYSV)]  process executing on ARM Cortex A9 target having Linux OS(KErnel 2.6.38.8 )

The process has user id root, groupid root.

Even when the process crashes after getting SIGSEGV, there is no core file generated.
Now I have read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732983/core-dump-file-is-not-generated) to ensure that the file system is writable, `ulimit -c` is unlimited, user is root and has permissions, but still, something is missing.

Here are a few outputs of certain variables of my process and system, related to a core file creation:

> cat /proc//coredump_filter is **00000033**

> cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern is **core**

> cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_uses_pid is **0**

I have tried everything but am stumped.

Could there be any kernel config/build option disabling the core creation?

Any other pointers?

**EDIT:**
I did simple test as below and it created a core file, but my process crash still does not dump core file.

```
sleep 20 &
killall -SIGSEGV sleep
```

Comment: Why do you think your process has *crashed*?  If it catches a signal, then a **core** file will not be generated.  Try adding an `atexit()` or other hook.  You can wrap your code in a shell script to verify if it exits *normally* or not.

Comment: Because I see it receiving SIGSEGV, and there is no signal handler set for that as i know it.

Comment: How do you *see it receiving*?  Via a debugger, with `strace`, or some other way?  Whatever tool you are using may circumvent the *core* generation.

Comment: @artless noise There is no tool or debugger attached. Just on the console , i see that process receiving SIGSEGV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could there be any kernel config/build option disabling the core creation?

It is hidden under **General Setup|Embedded System** or **General Setup|Configure standard...** depending on your Linux version.  The symbol value is `ELF_CORE` and it is in [init/Kconfig](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/init/Kconfig?id=refs/tags/v3.12-rc5#n1375).  If it is not enabled, you will never get core dumps.

As suggested in a hidden comment in [why coredump file is not generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18354686/why-coredump-files-is-not-generating-here).

Comment: Thanks. My Linux kernel on ARM target has no /usr/src or /boot to check config file to see what it was configured with. In that case how can I check what all options the kernel was configured with? Sorry what are these options - "General Setup|Embedded System or General Setup|Configure standard."

Comment: The menus I gave are Linux *kernel* configuration menus, where *top-menu|sub-menu* is fairly standard as to where to find the menu.  However, as your edit shows you are able to generate a *core*, this is not your problem (but was part of your question).  Some Linux configurations include the config in */proc/config.gz*.  As well, this maybe a module which is even better as it takes no space in memory.  However, you know you have it set as you can generate a *core* file.

Comment: So then any further pointers why core is not getting created on this process?

Comment: `ulimit` must be set to allow them.