# Why kill command does not generate core while gcore can?

Tags: linux, gcore

I can use gcore generating the core file of my application which was built with debug symbol. Out of curiosity, I tried using kill command to generated the core file, but no core is generated.

Here are the steps I took:

I first ran the following commands:

```
ulimit -c unlimited
sudo sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern=/tmp/core-%e.%p.%h.%t
```

Then start the application.

Then I tried the SIGABRT, SIGTRAP, SIGQUIT, there is no core file generated:

```
kill -SIGABRT  `pidof my_app`
kill -SIGTRAP  `pidof my_app`
kill -SIGQUIT  `pidof my_app`
```

In all these runs, my_app was stoped, but there is no core file, locally or /tmp.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Do you see anything wrong?

Comment: See [Why Coredump files is not generating here?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18354686/3422102)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965/how-to-generate-a-core-dump-in-linux-on-a-segmentation-fault